# Is it possible to shuffle a 3x3 Rubik's cube so that there's no more than 2 pieces of the same color in every face?

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, recreational-mathematics, rubiks-cube

I'm not sure if this question belongs here but I see lots of Rubik Cube's questions around so here it goes:

Can I take a standard $3 \times 3$ Rubik's Cube and shuffle it so that, for every face, there are no more than $2$ pieces with the same color?

Thanks

**Please answer if you have managed (or failed) to solve the question using an actual cube. No guessing here, thanks.**

Comment: I would add the tag "group-theory"

Comment: Did you try it? It seems very easy to do...

Comment: Did YOU try it, @KarolisJuodelė? It's not a matter of seeming easy but of actually doing it.

Comment: @Adrian, yes, I did. "seems" might have been a poor choice of wording.

Comment: I have answered this here. [No more then two colors per side](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/52975/is-it-possible-to-scramble-a-rubiks-cube-so-that-each-face-has-no-more-than-2-s/53002#53002)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mean like this?

https://alg.cubing.net/?alg=M-_E-_S_L_B2

To find the solution just click "play".

EDIT:
By the way, the movements to get this setup are:

M' E' S L B2

Anyway the question is quite interesting because I think there are not tons of solutions to this problem... so now I have two new questions...

Does anyone knows a shorter way?

How many different combinations of this setup exists?

Protip: In ruwix.com to get the M' and the E' you have to extend the panel by clicking on ">" button

Edit2:
This is the shortest algorithm I can imagine...

M' S E M' R U U

The last two steps can be done with U U, D D, F F or B B...

Comment: You're much likelier to get responses to your two follow-ups if you post a new question, linking to this one as appropriate. :)

Comment: You are surely right, but I don't know if this questions deserve a new topic, may be does not...

Answer (score 2):

I believe this works.  Rotate diagonally opposite pairs of corners so that the front faces move to the sides.  Rotate the vertical center slice by a half-turn.  Interchange the four edge cubies around the equator.

Comment: I have tried to reproduce your solution. No luck. Had a cuber friend try it and same result. Have you positively managed to achieve the required result using an actual cube or just guessing ?

Comment: Or please provide instructions on how to reproduce using an online rubik's like http://ruwix.com/online-rubiks-cube-solver-program/

Comment: @Adrian:  I just guessed it.  I thought you could twist any pair of corners as described.  I have lost track of my algorithms for manipulating the cube, so used a rigid cube and looked at where the faces go.